# Google Cloud Run: "FAILED_PRECONDITION: due to quota restrictions" but real quota not reached yet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am encountering an issue while deploying my NodeJS server using Google Cloud CLI and would appreciate some guidance. Here is the process I followed:

1. Executed `npm run build` for my project, which completed successfully.
2. Set up Google Cloud service account and authenticated it.
3. Configured Docker with Google Cloud using `gcloud auth configure-docker`.
4. Set the Google Cloud project ID and the region for Cloud Run.
5. Tried deploying my service to Cloud Run using `gcloud run deploy`.

However, the deployment fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) FAILED_PRECONDITION: failed precondition: due to quota restrictions, cannot run builds in this region. Please contact support
```

Here are some details about my setup:

- NodeJS version: 18.12.0
- Google Cloud CLI version: latest 457.0.0
- Region: `europe-west3`

I suspect the issue might be related to quota restrictions in the `europe-west3` region, but I'm unsure how to confirm or resolve this. I have checked my account quota restrictions and it's okay, haven't reached it yet. Has anyone else faced a similar issue, or does anyone know how to work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update (25/01/24)

A few users have upgraded to v460.0.0, and confirmed that this issue is now fixed.

### Problem

On the [Google Cloud CLI version 456.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#45600_2023-12-05) it was added the following:

> Network Security
>
> - Add `--billing-project` required flag to `gcloud network-security firewall-endpoints create` command to provide Google Cloud project ID
>   for API enablement check, quota, and endpoint uptime billing.
> - Add `--update-billing-project` flag to `gcloud network-security firewall-endpoints update` command to update the Google Cloud project
>   used for API enablement check, quota, and endpoint uptime billing. So
>   it might be related.

And the [--billing-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/billing/projects/link#--billing-account) command seems like a beta feature:

> (BETA) This command sets or updates the billing account associated
> with a project.
>
> --billing-project=BILLING_PROJECTThe Google Cloud project that will be charged quota for operations performed in gcloud. If you need to
> operate on one project, but need quota against a different project,
> you can use this flag to specify the billing project. If both
> billing/quota_project and --billing-project are specified,
> --billing-project takes precedence. Run $ gcloud config set --help to see more information about billing/quota_project.

So I would recommend to set this value to your correct billing project, but even so, it feels like something is wrong from their side.

For more info: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/billing/projects/link

### Solution

I simply downgraded to 455.0.0 again and it deployed without a problem.

#### How to downgrade?

If you're deploying via GitHub actions:

```
 - name: Cloud run deploy
    uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v2"
    with:
      ...
      gcloud_version: "455.0.0"
```

With gcloud CLI:

```
gcloud components update --version=445.0.0
```

With Gitlab deploy (.gitlab-ci.yml):

```
image: google/cloud-sdk:455.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Have experienced this with the latest GitHub actions deploy-cloudrun as well.

For anyone that arrives here experiencing the bug through GitHub actions you can pin the CLI version for example:

```
 - name: Cloud run deploy
        uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v2"
        with:
          service: ${{ inputs.service_name }}
          region: ${{ inputs.region }}
          source: ./
          project_id: ${{ inputs.project }}
          gcloud_version: "455.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just downgrade to version 455.0.0 with this tip command:

```bash
gcloud components update --version=445.0.0
```

And now every thing works well again.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue as well. my gcloud version 456. then I just update to the latest version (v465.0.0). and the issue was gone.